# Git config --global user.email = "email@example.com" and user.name error in GitHub action

Tags: git, github-actions

I am trying to create a GitHub action for a react project. Essentially there are 2 steps I want the action to do:
1. `npm install`
2. `npm run deploy`
But my action run fails on
`Git config --global user.email = "email@example.com"` and `Git config --global user.name"`
The `npm run deploy` command does among other things, a `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` so I need to somehow pass the appropriate credentials to the action to allow for those commands. Anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: `git` are all in lowercase and you don't need the `=` before `user.email`. And the other comand you should use as `git config --global user.name "Your name here"`.

Comment: That git message is the error I receive from the action, not the command i ran

Comment: Can you please run `git config --list --global` to check the stored values for these first?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the email and user, you can do it one of two ways:

```
import { context } from '@actions/github';

await exec(`git config --local user.name "${context.actor}"`);
await exec(`git config --local user.email "github-action-${context.actor}@users.noreply.github.com"`); // This is basically a bogus email, but you get the idea
```

or

```
import { context } from '@actions/github';

const author = context.payload.commits[0].author; // Be careful using this, it may not always be here. For example, in the case of a pull_request triggered action, this will result in an error.
await exec(`git config --local user.name "${author.name}"`);
await exec(`git config --local user.email "${author.email}"`);
```

As described in my comments above, there are pros and cons to each.